# How can I add password fields to the account creation page?

Tags: users

My site has recently gone live, and I'm finding that a lot of users are getting confused while signing up for an account. I have "require email verification" enabled, so users are receiving their email with the one-time login link, but they don't seem be setting their passwords with this login. So they enter their details, save the profile and then, for whatever reason, log out and can't get back in as they never set a password.

I know they can request a password reset to get back in, but is there any way to add the password fields to the account creation page and still keep email verification?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it doesn't mention it on the module description page, this is one of the [features of LoginToboggan](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), which also addresses a number of other common login confusions (ie: a user can log in with their email address or username, prompt for login instead of permission denied page).

From the [documentation](https://drupal.org/node/1288722):

> **Set password**
>   Ticking this will allow users to enter their desired password when they set up their user account.

Comment: Wow! Why is this not part of drupal core already?! The flow of account creation and login actually make sense now. Thank you soooo much for showing me the light! ;)

Comment: Yes it was a revelation to me too. Now its in my "must have" toolkit along with Views and Features.

Answer (score 0):

The [User Registration Password module](https://drupal.org/project/user_registrationpassword) directly address this requirement:

> Let users register with a password on the registration form when
>   verification mail is required.
>
> By default, users can create accounts directly on the registration
>   form, set their password and be immediately logged in, or they can
>   create their account, wait for a verification e-mail, and then create
>   their password. With this module, users are able to create their
>   account along with their password and simply activate their account
>   when receiving the verification email.